# Does $form_state['redirect'] require a rebuild?

Tags: 7, forms, redirection

I'm working on a multi-step form, and one of the last steps is a confirmation page with a 'Continue' and 'Cancel' button. If they hit cancel, I want it to go to a whole other page.

I have a custom submit handler for the cancel button, but the functionality doesn't appear to be working. I have:

```
function hook_form_cancel_submit($form, &form_state) {
  drupal_set_message('Cancelled');
  unset($form_state['rebuild']);
  $form_state['redirect'] = array('another/page');
}
```

I don't want the form to be rebuilt after cancellation, but then I wonder how my redirect would get triggered, since it exists only in `$form_state`?

Comment: Could you maybe use `drupal_goto` instead of the redirect, or do you need to keep the values of the form intact and usable?

Comment: `drupal_goto()` is not used in form submission handlers.

Comment: @kiamlaluno "Should not be used", or "will not work"?

Comment: It is useless to use `drupal_goto()`, since Drupal will call the function for you; then, as Chris Pliakas rightly reported, calling it from a form submission handler would avoid other submission handlers are called too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Form generation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/group/form_api/7) reports the following text:

> `$form_state['redirect']` is used to redirect the form on submission. It may either be a string containing the destination URL, or an array of arguments compatible with `drupal_goto()`. See `drupal_redirect_form()` for complete information.

The function [drupal_redirect_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_redirect_form/7) is called by [drupal_process_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_process_form/7), which calls it after executing the form submission handlers with [form_execute_handlers()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_execute_handlers/7).

```
if ($form_state['submitted'] && !form_get_errors() && !$form_state['rebuild']) {
  // Execute form submit handlers.
  form_execute_handlers('submit', $form, $form_state);

  // ...

  // If batches were set in the submit handlers, we process them now,
  // possibly ending execution. We make sure we do not react to the batch
  // that is already being processed (if a batch operation performs a
  // drupal_form_submit).
  if ($batch = & batch_get() && !isset($batch['current_set'])) {
    // ...
  }

  // Set a flag to indicate the the form has been processed and executed.
  $form_state['executed'] = TRUE;

  // Redirect the form based on values in $form_state.
  drupal_redirect_form($form_state);

  // ...
}
```

In short, the form is not rebuild, before redirecting the user to a new page. The `$form_state` array that is passed to `drupal_redirect_form()` is the same array passed to `form_execute_handler()` (the difference is that the form handlers can add or alter values contained in `$form_state`).

Comment: That's a lot of copied and pasted code before getting to an answer! :D

Comment: I always try giving the proof of what I am saying, rather than leaving the task of finding out if I am correct to who asked the question. `:-)`

Comment: I think part of the idea of a site like this is that it's not up to the asker *or* the answerer to find out if an answer is correct -- the *community* can comment, upvote, or downvote an answer, which helps the asker decide on the reliability of the information.

Comment: An answer such as "No, it is not rebuild." is surely less useful than an answer that is more extended, and that points to the involved code.

Comment: Yeah, but you can put the answer at the beginning. Halfway through I was about to bail because I wasn't sure if you were getting to an answer or chastising me for not RTFMing :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `drupal_goto()`

```
function mymodule_form_cancel_submit($form, $form_state){
  drupal_goto('destination_path');
}
```

Comment: As a point of best practice, it is not advisable to use drupal_goto() in submit handlers as it stops script execution and redirects immediately.  Therefore it kills any overrides and prevents other submit handlers from firing.

Comment: This is good to know.  However, for cancellation isn't this good.